# working with .aggregate with node.js without mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking for a solution to my problem.
I try to .aggregate  and adding a field to my documents but it will not work it's not adding the field to the documents

```
db.collection("piet").aggregate([{
  $addFields: {
    "fuel_type": "unleaded"
  }
}], function (err, data) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.log('ddd', data)
})
```

Comment: The query looks fine. Do you not get the field `fuel_type` added to the result documents when you console `console.log('ddd', data)`?

Comment: no i dont get it logged

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var aggCursor = db.collection("piet").aggregate([{
  $addFields: {
    "fuel_type": "unleaded"
  }
}]);

await aggCursor.forEach(doc => console.log(doc));
```